next.js .. special chars remove my full uuid in dynamic route
My goal is to get username (test#123) from the url of (localhost/profile/test#123) . I have the route setup using folders [profile] -> profile -> [uuid] -> page.tsx
My issue is that the params only reads doesn't read anything after the specfial char in the username.
import React from 'react';

import UserProfilePage from '@/screens/UserProfilePage';

const OtherProfileView = ({ params }) => {
  console.log('----------- reading params username is: ', params);

  return <UserProfilePage account={{ params }} />;
};

export default OtherProfileView;


expection : http://localhost:3000/profile/testMe#6216   -> params: {  uuid : testMe#6216 }
actual : http://localhost:3000/profile/testMe#6216 -> params : {  uuid : testMe }

Maybe this could help. Having #something in url means that you are looking for an anchor tag, allowing the users to scroll directly to that position and keep track of page sections in url (imagine having <div id="6216"></div> in your page basically)
I guess the safest way is to encode the actual id using something like encodeURIComponent

thank you , but in my case I need to keep the # in the URL as is and read it ... if I encoded the URI the username will not be the same
